# SyntaxHighlighter doesn't work with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, xml, syntaxhighlighter

I used [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) API to highlight the given xml snippet.The xml string generate from server side and angular controller set value into the html page.

**Sample HTML snippet**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <pre id="xmlText" class="brush:xml">{{xml}}</pre>       
</div>
```

**AngularJs controller snippet**

```
//code goes here
$scope.xml=data.xml;
```

data fetching successfully.but the problem was that when set **xml** content into `<pre>` via `{{xml}}` nothing display.Please let me know how to solve this.

Note:I have included necessary SyntaxHighlighter  files.when i manually copy some xml string into `pre` its works fine.but via Angular model its empty.